Name of (90’s?) movie or tv that had an alien scorpion creature that attaches to a forearm as a weapon/tool?
Name of (90’s?) movie or tv that had an alien scorpion creature that attaches to a forearm as a weapon/tool? I think it was kept in a briefcase and was not meant for the person it was put on but the situation left no other option.

Reminds me of The Mummy Returns… But not alien and not a weapon.

There was a stargate episode with scorpion looking like tool that attached to the arm and gave the wearer super speed.  They were also kept in cases/briefcase.  SG1 needed the super speed to get onto a planet, but the tool was made for made for different people/aliens.

This was a movie or TV show and not a computer game? I seem to remember something similar in a game, but for the life of me I can't think of which one.

@crip659: I think these must be the Atanik armbands, but I'm not sure I'm seeing the visual similarity to a scorpion.

The Tavlek gauntlet from Farscape was used in emergencies by the entire crew in one episode - but, like the Atanik armbands, it doesn't look like much like a scorpion.


Name of (90’s?) movie or tv that had an alien scorpion creature that attaches to a forearm as a weapon/tool?

The genetically enhanced Skrill used by Taelon companions on Earth: Final Conflict match the first sentence. They look (remotely) insectoid/arachnid, are attached to the wrist/forearm, and can fire powerful energy bolts. The Skrill were explicitly likened to scorpions in the title of at least one episode.
And this TV series was released in the 1990s.

I think it was kept in a briefcase and was not meant for the person it was put on but the situation left no other option.

This, however, does not ring a bell for the aforementioned series. I don't remember any episode where such a scenario would be shown.
On the other hand, it sounds exactly like what seemed to happen with one of the neural parasites in the episode "Conspiracy" of Star Trek: The Next Generation - also insect-like in appearance, but attaching inside the host's neck. In that episode, an Admiral Quinn brings a parasite in a briefcase that is "meant for the Doctor", but Quinn wants to apply it to Commander Riker instead.

 It turns out to be a ruse; Riker is not actually implanted with it.

Maybe you are somehow conflating memories from these two shows?

I'm pretty sure there was an episode of earth final conflict where someone stole a Skrill, and it was in a briefcase at some point.

@Baronet_Canid: Stole a skrill? Very possibly the one episode my answer explicitly mentions. Not sure whether it was in a briefcase, though; it's possible, but I cannot currently find any proof for it.

I have along surgical scar the length of my arm, with little scars from the staples used to close the wound alongside.... It looks like I have a subdermal skrill :)
